# 90 days exit to return to Schengen

Tags: schengen, 90-180-visa-rules

I'm a little confused about the 90/180 day visa program. I'm from Argentina and my son is Dutch. I stayed in the Netherlands for 79 days and wish to come back for his birthday. That is in 93 days.

Since I left the Schengen area for over 90 days, does that mean that I reset my visa and I can reenter again for 90 days or do I have to wait for the 180 days to pass to renter for 90 days?

Comment: Based on what you wrote, you are good to go.